# Backward Concatenation of Column values(Strings) in Python pandas

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas

I trying to concatenate strings by decremented columns and assuming the table is as below. I'm creating fixed number (5) of NEW columns & want every column to have string concatenated by non-empty strings. Let say for the `row-1`, first concatenation will be `STR_1;STR_2;STR_3` and the second concatenation should be `STR_1;STR_2` and third concatenation should be `STR_1` & the rest of the cells should remain empty.

```
MAJOR_BRAND | SUB_SEGMENT | PACKAGE_TYPE | PACKAGE |  SIZE   | FLAVOR  | VOLUME
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STR_1       | STR_2       | STR_3        |         |         |         |
STR_1       | STR_2       | STR_3        |         |         |         | STR_7
STR_1       |             |              | STR_4   | STR_5   | STR_6   | STR_7
STR_1       |             | STR_3        |         |         | STR_6   | STR_7
STR_1       |             | STR_3        |         |         | STR_6   |
```

Output should looks like

```
 STR_JOIN_1                   | STR_JOIN_2             | STR_JOIN_3      | STR_JOIN_4 | STR_JOIN_5
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STR_1;STR_2;STR_3             |STR_1;STR_2             |STR_1            |            |
STR_1;STR_2;STR_3;STR_7       |STR_1;STR_2;STR_3       |STR_1;STR_2      |STR_1       |       
STR_1;STR_4;STR_5;STR_6;STR_7 |STR_1;STR_4;STR_5;STR_6 |STR_1;STR_4;STR_5|STR_1;STR_4 | STR_1   
STR_1;STR_3;STR_6;STR_7       |STR_1;STR_3;STR_6       |STR_1;STR_3      |STR_1       |
STR_1;STR_3;STR_6             |STR_1;STR_3             |STR_1            |            |
```

Kind help will be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: So the concatenation operation should go from left to right over all the columns of the dataframe, yielding each additional concatenation of one more string, and stopping the process at the first empty string found in a column? Also, regarding the second row, when you say that `the second concatenation should be STR_1;STR_2`, why is it not STR_1;STR_2;STR_3? EDIT: I got it, by "first concatenation" you mean the last concatenation, you got the operations in reverse order. You will need to recursively .apply() a function on the dataframe, and this function should check for empty strings first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty. Note f-strings require Python 3.6+.

```
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=[f'STR_JOIN_{i}' for i in range(1, 6)])

res['STR_JOIN_1'] = df.apply(lambda x: ';'.join(filter(None, x)), axis=1)

for i in range(2, 6):
    res[f'STR_JOIN_{i}'] = res[f'STR_JOIN_{i-1}'].str.split(';').str[:-1].str.join(';')
```

Result:

```
print(res)

                      STR_JOIN_1               STR_JOIN_2         STR_JOIN_3  \
0              STR_1;STR_2;STR_3              STR_1;STR_2              STR_1   
1        STR_1;STR_2;STR_3;STR_7        STR_1;STR_2;STR_3        STR_1;STR_2   
2  STR_1;STR_4;STR_5;STR_6;STR_7  STR_1;STR_4;STR_5;STR_6  STR_1;STR_4;STR_5   
3        STR_1;STR_3;STR_6;STR_7        STR_1;STR_3;STR_6        STR_1;STR_3   
4              STR_1;STR_3;STR_6              STR_1;STR_3              STR_1   

    STR_JOIN_4 STR_JOIN_5  
0                          
1        STR_1             
2  STR_1;STR_4      STR_1  
3        STR_1             
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Approach..i guess

```
new_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['STR_JOIN_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(initial_data.columns))])

loc = 0
for i in range(len(initial_data)):#initial_data being the input

    temp_list = [ x for x in list(initial_data.loc[i].values) if x ]

    new_data.loc[loc] = ['']*(len(initial_data.columns)-1)

    for j in range(len(temp_list)):
        new_data['STR_JOIN_{}'.format(j+1)][loc] = ';'.join(data[:len(data)-j])

    loc+=1
```